# Best plugins and gems for parsing email ala Highrise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am looking for recommendations on the best Rails plugins and gems for parsing email and inserting it into the database, similar to the way Highrise and Basecamp (among others) work.

Described here http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowToReceiveEmailsWithActionMailer

Are there any that people recommend, currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [astrotrain](http://github.com/entp/astrotrain/tree/master). I haven't used it myself, but I gather it's what the [entp](http://entp.com) guys are using for their apps.

Comment: Yeh i discovered this after a little searching.  Looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

Scott,

Perhaps some more information would be better? What exactly are you needing to do with the e-mails? Parse them?

Natural language parsing is an entire topic all unto itself, of course. But I doubt anyone's needs would go so deep as to need to parse natural language for something like this.

Fetching/receiving the e-mail is simple enough, as you've provided in a link yourself. I personally would go with the route of the example under "Receiving with Net::POP3/IMAP", since I detest setting up any sorts of mail servers on a unix box. Imho, it'd be the absolute easiest to set up a google mail account (http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/details.html) and connect to that using a cron'd script (NOT using script/runner, heh).

Once you do that, setting up a parser to interpret commands via subject line and to import messages in the body would be trivial. Which is likely why there aren't any plugins built for something like this yet.

Sorry if this wasn't exactly the answer you were looking for, but it seems pretty simple to just roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

In 2011 with Rails 3 the approach that I've used is to integrate the mail fetcher with the rails ActionMailer.

https://github.com/look/fetcher

ActionMailer does the work of parsing the email using the underlying mail library:
https://github.com/mikel/mail

Answer (score 1):

try https://github.com/titanous/mailman

From the README:
Mailman is an incoming mail processing microframework (with POP3 and Maildir support), that works with Rails "out of the box".

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I have to recommend Mailman. We use it in production to check an email account and then parse content or attachments using Nokogiri. Even went so far as to daemonize it on our (Ubuntu) server.